# SQL query with left join does not allow use of column from previous table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am forming a sql query like below which gives me an error that i cannot use m1.id in inner where clause.

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    m.member_no,
    mc.card_no
FROM
    customer AS c

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            membership
        WHERE
            creation_date = (SELECT MAX(creation_date) FROM membership AS m1 WHERE m1.cust_id = 123)
    ) AS m ON m.cust_id = c.id

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            member_card
        WHERE
            emboss_date = (SELECT MAX(emboss_date) FROM member_card AS mc1 WHERE mc1.membership_id = m.id)
    ) AS mc ON mc.membership_id = m.id
WHERE
    c.id = 123
```

Table : 
Customer, Membership, Member_card. 
Customer can have many membership and each membership can have many member_card.

Table Customer

```
id  name        address
1   amit            abc
2   mohit           xyz
3   rahul           asdf
4   ganesh          pqr
```

Table membership

```
id  member_no   creation_date   cust_id
21  123         21-09-1978          1
31  234         21-09-1988          2
41  345         21-09-1998          1
51  456         21-09-1977          2
```

Table member_card

```
id   card_no        membership_id   emboss_date
111  12345          21              21-09-1978
222  23456          31              21-09-1977
333  34567          21              21-09-1976
444  456789         41              21-09-1975
```

cust_id is foriegn Key in membership table
membership_id id foreign key in member_card table

Now, i want the customer details of all customer table with latest member_no(w.r.t creation_date) and card_no(w.r.t emboss_date), Even if a customer does not have membership, the customer details should be there. refer the query above i made
So, there should be one record for one customer, i.e the final result should contain 4 rows with data from all three tables

Comment: What DBMS are you actually using? You tagged this question with both `mysql` and `oracle` (just because Oracle owns MySQL doesn't mean they're the same DBMS).

Comment: provide your table structure and sample data also

Comment: I do not recommend using `SELECT MAX(...` inside a `WHERE` clause. If this is inside a stored-procedure or multi-statement function then you could cache those as intermediate variables - otherwise I think you should reformulate those as joins.

Comment: @Dai Do you require any more details?

Comment: @Tausifmohammad Yes, please also post the full table structure, and you should modify your query to remove all `SELECT *`, you should always explicitly name the columns you want, only use `SELECT *` in ad-hoc queries.

Comment: @Dia.. i added more details in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join`s should go with proper `subquery`

```
select 
       c.id, m.member_no, mc.card_no
from customer c
left join (
     select * from membership m
     where creation_date = (select max(creation_date) 
                            from membership where cust_id = m.cust_id)
) m on m.cust_id = c.id 
left join (select * from member_card mc
     where emboss_date = (select max(emboss_date) 
                          from member_card where membership_id = mc.membership_id) 
) mc on mc.membership_id = m.id
where c.id = 123
```

Other version with aggregation instead of `correlation`

```
select 
       c.id, m.member_no, mc.card_no
from customer c left join (
      select cust_id, max(creation_date) creation_date 
      from membership 
      group by cust_id) m 
on m.cust_id = c.id left join (
      select membership_id, max(emboss_date) emboss_date
      from member_card mc
      group by membership_id) mc 
on mc.membership_id = m.cust_id 
where c.id = 123
```

Comment: Hey, you missed a closing bracket on the second join. Thanks it works now .

Comment: this sql query works fine but takes a lot of time, any suggestion on how to improve this query ?

Comment: @Tausifmohammad... Do the aggregation in inner query.

Comment: this query : select cust_id, max(creation_date) creation_date 
      from membership 
      group by cust_id   .. does the full table scan , can we not put a where clause where it picks only the particular customer and then gets the max date.

Comment: One problem, your aggregation version does give the max(creation_date) but it does not give the cust_id corresponding to the max creation_date. Can we not compare the 'cust_id' from membership to 'id' from customer inside the left join query ?

Comment: @Tausifmohammad.. could u provide some sample data & desired result so, i would go through ? cause above is just fixing your current query structure not intended to any optimization.